# Out of curiosity, why are ConstraintLayout and LinearLayout declared inconsistently?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-constraintlayout

In the Android Documentation, you are required to write `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout` to declare a ConstraintLayout.  To declare a LinearLayout, all you need is `LinearLayout`.  Why isn't this consistent?

For example: (Taken directly from from Android Documentation)

ConstraintLayout

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout ...>
             <Button android:id="@+id/button" ...
                 app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                 app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent/>
         </>
```

LinearLayout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:paddingLeft="16dp"
   android:paddingRight="16dp"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:gravity="center">

   <!-- Include other widget or layout tags here. These are considered
           "child views" or "children" of the linear layout -->

 </LinearLayout>
```

Why can't you just write `<ConstraintLayout ...` other than [That's Just the Way it Is](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cOeKidp-iWo)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why isn't this consistent?

`LinearLayout` is a framework class, in `android.widget`. The framework `LayoutInflater` knows to look in certain packages, such as `android.widget`, for bare class names like `LinearLayout`.

`ConstraintLayout` is from a library. The framework `LayoutInflater` does not know anything about this library, and it will not find `ConstraintLayout` in `android.widget` or other framework packages.

For library-contributed classes, we need to fully-qualify the class name in the XML element.

Comment: Interesting answer on its own, BUT then the question becomes "why doesn't the `AppCompatViewInflater` handle this scenario for you", and check for the prefix of the `android.support*` / `androidx.widget.*` things.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce: There is no requirement to use `ConstraintLayout` with AppCompat. You can use `ConstraintLayout` with an ordinary non-AppCompat activity or fragment. And, in that case, you are using the framework `LayoutInflater`. Also, you are assuming that AppCompat knows something about `ConstraintLayout`, and there is no dependency in that direction either. They could probably hack something in there, but my guess is that they are limiting the AppCompat element shenanigans purely to AppCompat widgets, not arbitrary other ones (`RecyclerView`, `CardView`, etc.) unrelated to AppCompat.